# Defining an array of functions with multiple indices and one variable

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I have a function `f` of one variable `x` and a 4 x 3 array `A storing constants. I'd like to make an array or table of functions`functionTable`that uses both the array`A`and function`f`. I tried something like this, but Mathematica doesn't seem to be reading the array entries.

```
functionTable = 
  Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, Function[x, A[i, j] + A[i, j]*f[x]]], 
    {b, 1, 3}, {x, 1, 4}, {m, 1, 3}]
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: i and j are never defined and b and m are never used.

Comment: Plus, to access list elements you need to use `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Probably.

```
A = Array[a, {3, 4}];
functionTable = A + A f@# &;
functionTable[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
arry = Array[a, {4, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]},
>  {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3]}, 
>  {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]},
>  {a[4, 1], a[4, 2], a[4, 3]}}
> ```

```
funcTable = 
  Map[With[{a = #}, Function[x, a (1 + f[x])]] &, arry, {2}];
```

This shows how the functions in `funcTable` can be evaluated at an arbitrary value `t`.

```
Table[funcTable[[i, j]][t], {i, 4}, {j, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1] (1 + f[t]), a[1, 2] (1 + f[t]), a[1, 3] (1 + f[t])}, 
>  {a[2, 1] (1 + f[t]), a[2, 2] (1 + f[t]), a[2, 3] (1 + f[t])}, 
>  {a[3, 1] (1 + f[t]), a[3, 2] (1 + f[t]), a[3, 3] (1 + f[t])}, 
>  {a[4, 1] (1 + f[t]), a[4, 2] (1 + f[t]), a[4, 3] (1 + f[t])}}
> ```